# Hosting .NET Core APP V2.2 to IIS Error 500

Tags: iis, .net-core, obfuscation, obfuscar

I have recently tried obfuscar tool to obfuscate .NET core v2.2 project , the project runs successfully by Kestrel but doesn't run on IIS , however , it runs on IIS without obfuscation.
I see error code 500 as response but there weren't any details.

I have downloaded .NET Core Hosting bundle and checked the logs but there were no details about the error.

Any help to find out the problem , or how to even show the detailed error?

Comment: Use out-of-process mode in your web.config please. The in-process hosting mode relies on certain classes by name, so you cannot obfuscate them.

Comment: @LexLi I tried this but still the same , give me 502  without any further details

Comment: please check your event viewer. If there is any exception thrown from .net core runtime, you will find it.  If no exception can be found in event viewer. It might be a first chance exception. Then you need to collect dump file with [debug diagnostic](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210) collection and analyze the dump file with WINDBG.

Comment: @samwu yes i check the event viewer no errors found there I can only see  something like process was shut down, so I updated to .net core 3.1 and it worked , still couldn't figure out the issue with .net core v2.2